# Android activity.stopLockTask() causing SecurityException

Tags: java, android, mdm

I am calling `stopLockTask` on an `Activity`, but after a few times of turning lock task mode on and off, the call will eventually cause a `Security Exception`:

`SecurityException`: Invalid uid, expected 0.

I am not sure why this is happening. The activity is the same one that called `startLockTask`, is not `null` when called, but it still throws the error.

Code is pretty simple, so not sure there is much as for snippets that will help. The Fragment is calling `getActivity().startLockTask()`, `getActivity.stopLockTask()`

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: my only guess is that by going in and out of the app the activity is no longer the same, but I have no idea how to prevent that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be setup with [DPC](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc) first. [Lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) explains this step by step; as it seems, there are only certain [devices](https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/devices) supported. The error message `SecurityException: Invalid uid, expected 0` generally means, that you're not running this as device owner or admin, which results in "nope". Since the recent GSuite to Workplace migration, there's also two levels of end-device management plans available - which may eventually limit or enable end-device management possibilities (I don't know). It's more difficult than setting up a single PC for kiosk mode - because not having `ROOT_UID` `0` generally translates to: "not owning the device" (contrary to what the sales person may have told you). That's why the `SecurityException` is being thrown ...unless taking device ownership first.

This [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) shows the environment you'd need for lock-task mode.
**But** the current status of this is unsure, as no more custom DPC will be accepted.
So this may not be wrongful, but stale to outdated information; see part two.

---

2021 Update.
Just seen that meanwhile the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management)
 is being suggested,
were a device policy alike this might be similar to what you're trying to do ...

It's not the app in lock-task mode, but the app being installed in `KIOSK` mode:

```
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.example.app",
    "installType": "KIOSK",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
]
```

There's also a [`google-api-services-androidmanagement`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-androidmanagement/v1) library,
which both may generally be the more future-proof alternative.

Comment: I am setting the app as the device owner via adb shell dpm set-device-owner. Without it I cannot enter lock task or do the many other things I am doing. On top of that, if I set lock task mode on a secondary app from within this one, I do not get the exception. Which doesnt make much sense since I am calling stopLockTask on a different activity. I think the issue I am seeing is more related to the fact when I close the window and come back something is happening in which the activity no longer matches the one that set it up. But again, I do the same thing when setting my launcher as locked

Comment: I will loom more into that api, but that seems more for external control where I need to be able to lock the device down from the device itself, and not managed from a central server.

Comment: Going to look more into that link with the manifest, I think the clue might be with the fact I do not have a service to persist the dpm. Thanks for all that info, will return with results.

Comment: It seems after updating some things and adding the service that I am finally not having the crash anymore. Will mark accepted once available, thank you